# How to call a procedure with Rollback in the end?

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I am working with PostgreSQL with DBeaver. I would like for test purposes to make a procedure call in a transaction; then to Rollback it. I have written the following script:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
 call MyProcedure();
ROLLBACK $$;
```

I have tried to run it in DBeaver console. I have got the following error:

`SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at end of input`
It pointed out to the final `$$`.

What is wrong; and how could I reach my goal: to make a procedure call in a transaction; then to Rollback it?

Answer (score 0):

For the DO block, you are missing the `end`

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'test';
    ROLLBACK;
END $$;
```

But since you want to display a table content, you can't use an anonymous block but instead just start/end the transaction.

```
BEGIN;
    select * from test;
    call my_procedure();
    select * from test;
ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does it mean that BEGIN is not only a block beginning, but it also starts a transaction? Then the END commits the transaction, correct?

Comment: Also: can the same be done with a function, not a procedure?

Comment: In case of error, there is no commit within the block. An anonymous block is a procedure, it doesn't return anything, but within it you can call whatever you want

Comment: Thank you. 
But I cannot, for instance, call within the block something like "select * from a_table" to see in DBeaver console - what is in the table "a_table" at the given moment.
Or it is possible?

Comment: No, anonymous blocks can't be used for viewing content. You must store in a variable (or similar) whatever you are selecting

Comment: "...No, anonymous blocks can't be used for viewing content" - I see.
What about procedures? Is there a way to insert "select * from a_table" into a procedure to see in DBeaver console - what is in the table "a_table" at the given moment ?

Comment: You don't need a transaction for a simple select

Comment: Yes I don't. But as I said before, I would like to do something like this:

DO $$
BEGIN
    call MyProcedure();
    select * from A_Table;
    ROLLBACK;
END $$;

The goal is to see - what MyProcedure() has modified in the A_Table; and then Rollback the modifications. This is a typical debugging technique. Earlier when I worked on MS T-SQL it was possible. Now I have moved to PostgreSQL, and see no way to do this.